# Codeigniter Select and (conditional) Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3, PHP and MySQL.

I'm trying to select a record from a MySQL database, and depending on the result run an update query.

```
If result = 0, update.
If result = 1, do nothing.
```

My code so far is;

```
public function addData($itemId) {
    $gDescription = 'test';
    $gPreviewLink = 'test';
    $gThumbnail = 'test';
    $gPageCount = 'test';

    $this->db->select('g_data');
    $this->db->from('item');
    $this->db->where('item_id', $itemId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result(); 
    // var_dump($result) returns array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["g_data"]=> string(1) "0" } }

        $data = array(
        'item_description'  => $gDescription,
        'item_preview_link' => $gPreviewLink,
        'item_thumbnail'    => $gThumbnail,
        'item_pageCount'    => $gPageCount,
        'g_data'            => '1',
        'g_data_timestamp'  => 'NOW()'
        );
        // if result = 0 update
        if($result == '0') {
        $this->db->where('item_id',$itemId);
        $this->db->update('item', $data);
    }
        }
```

Is there any reason the data won't update in my database? I'm not receiving any error messages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here...

Comment: is $result numeric or character?  top example shows numeric but you're == to a character '0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query->result()` returns an array of objects where each object is a row from the table. (As you can see in the var_dump in your comments)

Without other changes your conditional should be

```
if($result->g_data == '0') { ...
```

That said, you should have checked earlier in the method that the database atually returned results. Also, you don't need more than one row so don't use `result()` use 'row()' instead

```
...
$query = $this->db->get();
// The following will set $result to the value of "g_data" if there 
// are rows and to "0" if there are none.
$result = $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->row()->g_data: '0';
...
```

If you do the above then the conditional can remain as you have it coded

```
if($result == '0') {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing the SELECT query means making an unnecessary extra trip to the database.  Just build your `0` criteria into your UPDATE query -- if it is not satisfied, then no rows will be affected.

Code:

```
$data = [
    'item_description'  => $gDescription,
    'item_preview_link' => $gPreviewLink,
    'item_thumbnail'    => $gThumbnail,
    'item_pageCount'    => $gPageCount,
    'g_data'            => '1'
];

$this->db->where([
    'item_id' => $itemId,
    'g_data'  => 0
]);
$this->db->set('g_data_timestamp', 'NOW()', false);
$this->db->update('item', $data);
// return (bool)$this->db->affected_rows();
```

All done in a single query execution.  I also took the liberty of demonstrating how to pass a MySQL function as a value using `set()`'s third parameter.